# mutt отправка письма со вложением на кириллице

Tags: email

Всем доброго времени суток!

Пытаюсь отправить письмо через mutt из шела, со вложением, у него длинное имя на кириллице.

На выходе у письма вложение получает имя "Часть 1.2", если файл переименовать на латиницу - все ок, подскажите, пожалуйста что нужно, чтобы вложение нормально выглядело.

```
echo | mutt -x -e "set smtp_url=smtp://серв" -e "set from="от кого"" -e "set charset="utf-8"" -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "тема" -i index.html -a "длинное имя на кириллице.pdf" -- кому
```

Comment: а откуда берется строка "Часть 1.2". Она содержится в теле письма, которое выводится командой echo?

Comment: и попробуйте убрать пробелы из названия файла, сделать например "длинное_имя.pdf"

Comment: и мне кажется что кавычки надо экранировать -e "set from=\"от кого\""

Comment: К сожалению изменять имя файла - не наш выход, ни в теле письма, ни во волжении строки "Часть 1.2" нету, если немного укоротить имя вложения - все нормально, но как только полное - сразу его переименовывает :(

Comment: немного - это сколько? поменять на данные момент нужно чтобы хотя бы диагностировать проблему.

Comment: 92 символа включая расширение, из них -9 пробелов

Comment: довожу до 46 символов из них 4 пробела - у вложения нормальное имя

Comment: неужели ни у кого не было похожих проблем? :(

Comment: скидывайте ваш .muttrc, может станет понятнее